# Contest Solution: Packet Sniffer

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

> **The Problem**
>
> Sniffed any good packets lately, dude? Hopefully you haven’t done this illegally, but rest assured that there
>   are some who have. If you surf the Internet, you have probably visited companies’ net sites where they sell
>   their products online: you give them your credit card number and they ship you the goods. That’s a
>   convenient way to shop if you can ensure that your credit card number isn’t being “sniffed” up by wily
>   hackers and used illicitly.
>
> The Internet is an example of a packet-switched network. This means that information is sent in
>   discrete groups of bits called packets from computer to computer. For example, when I send email to
>   someone in the Philippines, my message (at the binary level) is broken up into packets, and routed packet
>   by packet (not all at once) from computer to computer, ultimately to the recipient’s computer.
>
> “Packet sniffing” refers to writing a program that grabs the individual packets that come your
>   computer’s way and reads their contents. Now the term “packet sniffing” has obvious unethical
>   connotations: usually it refers to writing a program that reads packets addressed to computers other than
>   your own. But the principle is exactly the same when you only intercept those packets that are intended for
>   you.
>
> Let’s suppose that a network packet consists of three parts: a special start-of-packet bit pattern,the packet content, and a special end-of-packet bit pattern. Suppose that the start- and end-of-packet
>   pattern are both 1000001 and that the packet content is no more than three consecutive sequences of 7 bits(1’s and 0’s). So, to write a program to “sniff” packets you need only to write a program that scans its
>   input and “decodes” everything between pairs of 1000001.
>
> For this problem assume that the content of each packet is binary representation of no more than
>   three ASCII characters, each encoded in 7 “bits” (0’s and 1’s). Your task is to write a program that prints
>   out the message (in English) that is being transmitted by a sequence of packets.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> Take your input from the text file `prob4.in`. Here’s a sample of its content:
>
> ```
> 10000011100010110111111011111000001100000101000011000001
> ```
>
> You are guaranteed two things: (1) the encoding is correct, and (2) only lower case letters and punctuation are encoded in the packet.
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> Your program should direct its output to the screen. The correct output for the sample input above is:
>
> ```
> boo!
> ```

**packetsniffer.py**

```
with open('prob4.in') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().replace('1000001', '')
        print(''.join([chr(int(c, 2)) for c in [line[i:i+7] for i in range(0, len(line), 7)]]))
```

Any advice on performance enhancement, solution simplification or that is topical is appreciated!

Comment: So it cannot happen that '1000001' is generated by two consective asci characters?

Comment: @miracle173 My guess would be yes, since that violates some of the rules established by the problem. Though I wouldn't mind seeing that case handled ;)

Comment: which rule does this violate?

Comment: An empty packet would be kind of pointless. It's implied that we're going to be getting **something** btwn. the delimiting phrases. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: a package with an empty content does not violate the rules. The rule says "not more than three". But that was not my objection. I asked, what if  something like this happens "...1000  0001..", a char ending with 1000 is followed by a char starting with 0001? You say there is a packacge delimiter 10000001 and remove it, this is wrong.

Comment: Oh then no. When it says "everything between pairs of 1000001" it means the literal "10000001," interpreted as one char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good, except that you do not really need the `c`, and hence the nesting, in the list comprehension. You can use `line[i:i+7]` directly in `int`, making it a bit shorter:

```
''.join([chr(int(line[i:i+7], 2)) for i in range(0, len(line), 7)])
```

However, just removing the `1000001` in the line before seems a bit arbitrary, since (a) the pattern might also be present within a package, spanning two bytes. Instead, you could *keep* the `c` variable and ignore the current `c` if it equals the package delimiter:

```
>>> line = "10000011100010110111111011111000001100000101000011000001"
>>> ''.join([chr(int(c, 2)) for c in (line[i:i+7] for i in range(0, len(line), 7)) if c != "1000001"])
'boo!'
```

But, you still lose the information where the packages start and end.
Instead, you could use regular expressions for first detecting the packages, and then finding the bytes within those:

```
>>> p = r"1000001((?:[01]{7}){,3})1000001"
>>> re.findall(p, line)
['110001011011111101111', '0100001']
```

Here, `p` means "package delimiter, followed by up to three groups of seven `0` or `1`, followed by delimiter. Then you can use another regex `q` to split those into bytes.

```
>>> q = r"[01]{7}"
>>> [''.join(chr(int(x, 2)) for x in re.findall(q, y)) for y in re.findall(p, line)]
['boo', '!']
```

Of course, the regex `q` is a bit redundant, since we already checked the same in `p`. You could also do this part using a `range` and string slicing, but personally I still find the regex approach cleaner.

```
>>> [''.join(chr(int(y[i:i+7], 2)) for i in range(0, len(y), 7)) for y in r e.findall(p, bits)]
['boo', '!']
```

---

Another way, without regex, might be to first separate the line into groups of 7 bits, and then using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group those parts into package-delimiter and package-contents:

```
>>> parts = [line[i:i+7] for i in range(0, len(line), 7)]
>>> groups = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(parts, key="1000001".__ne__) if k]
>>> [''.join(chr(int(b, 2)) for b in g) for g in groups]
['boo', '!']
```